# Intellij Idea: how to completely remove a Version Control - Directory Mapping?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

My Idea project is on git version control.
In a subdirectory of my project I cloned a git repository from github for error and I deleted this repository dir that I cloned (I have not commit to project git).

What I noted is that on intellij project structure, `Version Control` -> `Directory Mapping` the dir that I deleted is listed in red with VCS `Git`.
I removed it with the delete button on this page but it still remains as `Unregistered roots:`.

How can I get rid of this directory mapping on Version Control? this directory doesn't exists anymore.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a record about this folder by going to `vcs.xml` under `.idea` folder and removing it from there

Comment: In my case, the removed module is not in `vcs.xml` but still shows up under Unregistered roots. Is it stored somewhere in global IDEA settings?